# SSIS Flat File Source

Tags: ssis

**Problem History**
I have a simple SSIS package which loads data from a flat file source(.csv) to a MS SQL Server table.
Falt File Format

[image]

All of sudden our source system added a header and footer to the input file so the file now looks like

[image]

**Question:**

The current SSIS package did not fail and is working fine; On top of it - it is not loading the header and footer. How is that SSIS pacakage ignores the header and footer? should'ent the package fail?

Answer (score 1):

SSIS Flat File Source is very simplistic and basically ignores file format changes as far as it can - it only really cares about the row terminator. Column identification is positional.  So I would expect it is skipping the first row, then passing on the 2nd row (Col1, Col2 etc) and the footer row.

Comment: This might be the answer also to my "issue", so let me ask, does this simplification also apply to the file name?
I have a flat file source connection that points to an alleged notification_aggregates.tsv.zip.tsv which is never there. The .tsv files in the target folder will have a YYYY-MM-DD-hh_mm_ss.tsv format. And yet the task loads them.